# hiding text on mobile and hiding on sizes above mobile

Tags: css

I'm hiding some text with the following code

```
/* Smartphones in portrait mode (0-401px) */
@media only screen and ( max-width: 401px ) {
    .dontdisplayonmobile    {
    display: none !important;
}
}
```

It stops it displaying on mobile. but the spacing it creates is still there so it's making the text go but not completely going as if there's nothing there.

I tried adding , but it didn't work

```
margin: 0 !important;
padding: 0 !important;
```

Any ideas.?

EDIT

Does anyone know the best way to media query when you want to hide something on anything above 401 px for example.

Do you just put 100000000 or similar so it never shows ?

Comment: That depends on what your layout is.

Comment: @MarshallMunoz, normally `visibility: hidden` hides the element, but keeps the space "reserved". `display: none` should 'remove' the element completely. @Nicholasuk can you reproduce the problem in a JSFiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qyucd6up/

Comment: also if it helps it's the second text box down, www.nicholasmassey.co.uk

Comment: the spacing on your website is from the p tag you dont hide with your class, not from the span you are using to hide for mobile

Answer (score 0):

On your site you have a span class called 'dontdisplayonmobie' that hides correctly when the viewport is less than 401 px. But your span class is in a paragraph (`<p> </p>`). P has a padding-bottom: 1em; which is the empty space you still see. Remove the padding-bottom of that paragraph when the viewport is less than 401 px and it should look fine.

[image]

Comment: yes that was the issue. I wrapped a p class around the text and set padding bottom to zero, so thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you only should need html like this

```
<span class="dontdisplayonmobile">Free Quotes. </span><span class="calltodayword">Call today.</span> <a href="tel:01216631202"><i class="fa fa-phone icon-phone"></i> 0121-663-1202</a>

@media only screen and ( max-width: 401px ) {
  .dontdisplayonmobile    {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

so you are only hiding the part with "Free Quotes"

Comment: yeah that's what i first did but i want to mess around with the way it displays on smaller screen, maybe have the word tap next to the number etc. So figured better to have separate control.i've wrapped a p tag around the text with a class and set the padding bottom to zero, that fixed it.